# Calculate transfers to equalize balances?

Tags: equality

I'm playing a MMORPG where we party hunt, the problem is that at the end of the hunt each person may have different balances depending on what items they wasted and the stuff each one looted.

The game tell us what are our balances in the party, but nothing more... so for example, having something like this as an input:

**Balances:**

- Person A: +132
- Person B: -50
- Person C: +70

I want to obtain the transfers to be made so that we all end up with the same balance, using the example from above:

**Transfers:**

- Person A should transfer 81 to B
- Person C should transfer 20 to B

So A ends up with 51, B ends up with 51 and C ends up with 50.

Is there a known algorithm for this? I would like to make a web app with this calculator.

Comment: There is an easy way to ensure that each player does at most one transfer. Ignore all players with neither a surplus or a deficit. Take any person $p$ with a balance surplus. Transfer all the surplus to any other player. Remove $p$ from the set of considered players. Repeat. Notice that, in general, each transfer can only settle the balance of at most $2$ players, so this is always $2$-approximation of the number of needed transfers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that isn't necessarily guaranteed to give the optimal solution but might be effective for small numbers.

Let $\delta_i$ be the amount that player $i$ is supposed to give: if $\delta_i>0$, they are giving away goods; if $\delta_i$, they are receiving goods. I will assume $\sum_i \delta_i = 0$.

In each step, find the smallest set $S$ of players you can find such that $\sum_{s \in S} \delta_s = 0$, i.e., the smallest subset that can given goods amongst themselves.  Then transfer among the players in $S$.  This can be done with $|S|-1$ transfers.  (Everyone with a surplus gives to one designated player who has a shortfall; then that designated player gives to everyone else who has a shortfall.)

Now repeat.

If there are $n$ players and you've partitioned the player into $k$ sets $S_1,\dots,S_k$, then in total you'll use $n-k$ transfers, so it is in your interest to partition into as many sets as possible, i.e., intuitively to make each set as possible.  That's the intuition for why this might be a reasonable strategy.

It won't necessarily find the optimal set of transfers, though.  I suspect that finding the optimal set of transfers is (weakly) NP-hard, by reduction from the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), but I haven't tried to check this carefully, so this statement might be incorrect.  It might even be strongly NP-hard, by reduction from [3-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem).

Comment: The problem, which as you say amounts to partitioning into a maximum number of zero-sum subsets, is NP-hard by reduction from Subset Sum: Given a SS instance $x_1, \dots, x_n$ with $T = \sum_i x_i$, if $T \ne 0$, add one more element $x_{n+1} = -T$; this ensures there is a solution to the corresponding equalisation problem that contains all $n+1$ players. Iff the optimal solution to it has $k \ge 2$ subsets, any of those subsets is a solution to the original SS instance.